# How do I use associations on a rake task, RoR5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I use associations on a rake task, RoR5

Hello
So I have a problem am trying to run daily verifications and daily updatestes on a rake task for each USER. current_user{helper} doesn’t work in a rake task .  So a user has an account, has deposits, has trades, has withdrawals,  when a users deposits, after which its status is true, in  every 10minutes, the deposit amount is added to the account balance. Dat belongs to their respective users.

Bt  ah can’t seem to be able to find accounts belonging to their users since { Account.where(user_id: current_user)} doesn’t work

Here are the specifics

Users Models

- :has_many :accounts*
- :has_many :deposits*
- :has_many :trades*

Account Model.
*belongs_to :user*
.
Deposit Model.
*belongs_to :user*
.

- @accounts = Account.where(user_id: current_user)*.

This Code doesn’t work on rake tasks bt I know there is a way to achieve same result in a rake file I don’t  need the cookies or sessions reference

I just need to sort lists belonging to a user in a rake file

```
desc "Depost Verification"
  task transaction: :environment do
    @deposits = Deposit.all
    @accounts = Account.all

  @accounts.zip(@deposits).each do |account, d|
      if d.status && d.confirmed
      acct_bal = account.balance.to_f + 0.00
      account.update!(balance: acct_bal)
      puts account.user.username
      puts account.balance
      print "Deposit Already Completed"
    elsif d.status
      acct_bal = account.balance.to_f + d.amount.to_f
      confirm = "true"
      status = "true"
      account.update!(balance: acct_bal)
      account.update!(status: status)

      d.update!(confirmed: confirm)

      puts account.user.username
      puts account.balance
      puts d.confirmed
      print "Deposit verifed Added"

    else
      print "No Deposit"
    end
  end

    print "Account Balnce Updated..........."

  end
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly but if you want to do something for each user why don't you just do something like this: `User.all.each { |user| do_stuff_for_user(user) }`?

Comment: A user has accounts and deposits

Comment: normally in controller you do  ``` @accounts = Account.where(user_id: :current_user )``` but in rake tasks the helper current_user cant work so

Comment: how do i lists accounts that belongs to a user 
or list deposits that have a user id  ie  deposits that belongs to a user inside a rake task

Comment: `User.all.each { |user| user.accounts }` should work when your associations are properly set up.